# is manual installation of findbugs plugin in sonarqube ok?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, findbugs

I have a fairly old sonarqube installation, which for various reasons I can't upgrade. I upgraded however the java plugin to 2.0, and run into an issue with multiple plugins being incompatible. I manually removed those plugins, and reinstalled them from the Upgrade Center once I was able to restart sonarqube. However, for whatever strange reason the findbugs plugin keeps failing to download from the center. I can however manually download the jar file from here:

`http://downloads.sonarsource.com/plugins/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/java/sonar-findbugs-plugin/2.0/sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.0.jar`

and manually copied it to `extensions/plugins/`, as explained [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin).

when I restart sonar-qube I don't see any problem in the log file, and in fact I see this:

```
2015.06.25 12:44:44 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [common-java/java]...
2015.06.25 12:44:44 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [common-java/java] done: 6 ms
```

However, something is fishy: if I go to the update center, I don't see `findbugs` listed under the installed plugins, and yet I don't see it under the available ones either.

Can somebody clarify what should be done to correctly install manually?

Also, when I go to the `Quality Profiles` section I see only two rows under Java:

```
                                Rules
SonarWay                          70  ...
SonarWay with Findbugs            70
```

This seems a very small number of rules, I know there should be many more...what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Plugin version 2.0 embedded FindBugs, so there's no need to download it independently. That's also why you're not seeing it in the download center. You should remove it and restart your server. That may resolve the issue with your profiles as well.